# How to use Firebase cloud messaging for web push with @nuxtjs/pwa plugin?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, nuxt.js, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to use Firebase cloud messaging for web push notifications with @nuxtjs/pwa plugin. I have followed [the official documentation](https://firebase.nuxtjs.org/service-options/messaging/), but I can't inject some code in the created service worker (to create setBackgroundMessageHandler for example) (see [the doc for inject](https://firebase.nuxtjs.org/service-options/messaging/#inject)).

And I can't find any example on that. Can someone can help me or provide me some example please ?